# how to get to spark plugs on a C109R Suzuki?

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki

How do I get to the spark plugs on a Suzuki C109R? I just bought the bike  and did not get a manual.

Comment: Do you mean "How do I remove the sparkplugs from the engine" or "How do I decide which sparkplugs to buy" or "Where do I buy sparkplugs"?

Comment: Start by removing the gas tank, then do the rest of the steps found here... http://www.m109riders.com/forums/showthread.php?t=167269

Comment: What year is the bike?